# Encrypt/Decrypt using DataProtection.DataProtector c#

Tags: c#, encryption, data-protection

I need to decrypt a conection that was created initially under an account that is no longer available.

In order to do that I made a simple app:

```
private void btnEncrypt_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {            
        DataProtection.DataProtector dp = new DataProtection.DataProtector(DataProtection.DataProtector.Store.USE_MACHINE_STORE);
        try
        {
            byte[] dbToEncrypt = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(txtText.Text);
            string resultEncrypted = Convert.ToBase64String(dp.Encrypt(dbToEncrypt, null));
            txtEncrypt.Text = resultEncrypted;                
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error: " + ex.Message);
        }
    }
private void btnDecrypt_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {            
        DataProtection.DataProtector dp = new DataProtection.DataProtector(DataProtection.DataProtector.Store.USE_MACHINE_STORE);
        try
        {
            byte[] dbToDecrypt = Convert.FromBase64String(txtEncrypt.Text);
            string resultDecrypted = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(dp.Decrypt(dbToDecrypt, null));
            txtDecrypt.Text = resultDecrypted;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error: " + ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Now, I have noticed that when I do a test in my computer, and try to decrypt the encrypted result in a different computer I get:

> Exception decrypting. Decryption failed. Key not valid for use in
>   specific state.

Then, I did some research and found out this:

> Did you export the key from one server to the other so they are both
>   set up the same? If not, you are using mismatched keys, which will
>   cause an encryption/decryption error.

and I can find the keys here:

> How to get the validationkey value and decryptionkey value?
>
> > decryption key can be found at "D:\Documents and Settings\All
> >     Users\Application Data\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\MachineKeys"

so my question is: If I export the keys in that location from my computer the the one I want to decrypt the data will that work? and by export mean just copy the key files or do another operation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK this is not possible - and in any case is not desirable.  DPAPI regularly creates new keys, so even if you could copy the keys between machines, they would become obsolete after a period of time.

If you want to decrypt data on more than one computer, use a different method, e.g. RSA.